# Common tangent between two parabolas

Tags: calculus

I am given two parabolas

$$y=x^2-5x+6$$ and $$y=x^2 +x+1$$
On simply equating $\text{d}y/\text{d}x$ I get $2x -5=2x+1$ which leaves me out at $-5=1$ , how to actually find the slope here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to solve the system of equations:
$$
2x_1-5=2x_2+1=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}
$$
Notice that the common-tangent may not pass the intersection of the two lines.